# Renewing a Portuguese passport 8 months before it expires

Tags: passports, passport-renewals, portugal, portuguese-citizens

I am a Portuguese citizen, and my Portuguese passport expires in May 2022. However, I am planning to go to Lisbon for a few days in October. I am wondering if one can renew a Portuguese passport 8 months before it expires.

Comment: Assuming that passport-renewals do not operate at a loss, they should be happy to take your money.

Comment: You will, very likely, get the standard lenght of vadility, no extra time for the 8 months.

Comment: Have you tried contacting password office?

Comment: Why not? Countries have different requirements for visa (and validity of passport), so it is common to have to renew in advance. Heavy travelers must also change more often due to lack of pages without stamps. 8 months is the usual time to renew passport.